# Using Hashmap contains method to check for a duplicate key

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

So i have an interface.

```
public interface ARecord {
    public BigInteger getAutoID();
    public String getACompId();
}
```

and

```
public class APPPRecord extends AbstratAPRecord implements ARecord{
    private BigInteger autoID;
    private String ACompId = null;
   //setter and getter}
```

In service,

```
    List<APPPRecord> PFRecord = null;
    while(scroll.next()){
      APPPRecord item = (APPPRecord) scroll.get(0);
      List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
      recs.addAll(PFRecord);
```

My PFRecord list has results that are being duplicated. I have to use hash maps that can check for ACompId contains key. If the key already exists don't pass it to recs.addAll. How can I go about doing this? Any help appreciated

Update: I tried Set and still see duplicate results with HashCode() and equals() in my model class.

```
    for(ARecord records:recs){
        uniqueRecs.put(records.getACompId(), records);
        Set<String> keys = uniqueRecs.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
            log.debug("keys " + key);
        }
        }
```

Also tried hashMaps.

```
    HashMap<String, ARecord > uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord >();
    for(ARecord records:recs){
    if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getACompId())){
        uniqueRecs.put(records.getACompId(), records);
        for (String key : uniqueRecs.keySet()) {
                log.debug("unique record " + key);
        }

        }

    }
```

Both of them still produce duplicate results. Any ideas?

Comment: where exactly have u implemented the `Map`?

Comment: beside ur probably better off using `Set`.

Comment: needs to be implemented after/before the last line in service where it checks for if the record is already present in PFRecord, don't pass it to recs.addAll.

Comment: @nafas. I have tried set, hash map, equals. It doesn't work. All I want to do is to check for the record if it exists already, don't pass it.

Comment: u need to override `equals` and `hashCode` method inside ur `ARecord` Method.

Comment: here is a perfect example for that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Replace `List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();`

with `Set<ARecord> recs = new HashSet<ARecord>();`

and make sure the implementations of the `ARecord` implements the `hashcode`/`equals` methods properly so that your set only contains ***distinct*** instances.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `HashMap<K,V>` class, This [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) will provide you with the required API.

And according to your requirement you can make use of `.containsKey(Object key)` method to check for the existence of the key already.

**Update:**  I suggested this because you asked for `HashMap`, if duplication is the only issue you have then you can make use of `.contains(Object o)` method on the List you already have in-place. the interface `List<>` provides this method which returns a `boolean` value based on the presence of the value.

Comment: hmm. This is what I need to implement but the use of custom array is confusing me. so far,

        Map<String, List<ACCMPatchRecord>> recsMap = new HashMap<String, List<ACCMPatchRecord>>();
recsMap.put(//need to pass in to APPPRecord. ACompId)
then check for .containskey()

Comment: Yeah you can make use of the autoId or generate some other unique id for each of the record.